# Setting ChoiceBox item too slow in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, concurrency, javafx

i have a problem with setting item in `ChoiceBox`, so basicly i must load data from a database i do it in another thread :

```
final Service<ObservableList<Country>> countryService = new Service<ObservableList<Country>>() {

            @Override
            protected Task<ObservableList<Country>> createTask() {
                return new Task<ObservableList<Country>>() {

                    @Override
                    protected ObservableList<Country> call() throws Exception {
                        Dao<Country, Integer> countriesDao = null;
                        List<Country> result = null;

                        try {
                            countriesDao = DaoManager.createDao(Connection.getNewInstance(), Country.class);
                            System.out.println("getting data");
                            result = countriesDao.queryForAll();
                            System.out.println("got data");
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ListClientsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(result);

                    }
                };
            }
        };

        countryService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                  // taking a lot of time here like 4-5 second and freeze
                  // the gui(normal because it executed in Javafx Application Thread

                 // but why its take so much time??
                 cbSearchCountry.setItems(countryService.getValue());
            }
        });


        countryService.start();
```

Normally database access should take a time longer that setting a list to a ChoiceBox, but no here fetching 150 record from my database is instantaneous but settings observable list to my ChoiceBox take about 5 seconds why?
because i have too much Node in my current Scene??

Comment: Your code seems to me ok, so maybe you can try to create the result as an ObservableList in the `setOnSucceeded` method (if it is the FX-Thread). Is `countriesDao.queryForAll()` async? Or is it blocking?

Comment: Yes query all is blocking that why i put ita in another thread

Comment: If you replace your real database code with code that just blocks for some time and then returns a fixed list of 150 items does it show the same behavior? If so, use that to create a [MCVE]. Also note that a `ChoiceBox` is explicitly intended for a small number of items. You might try a `ComboBox` instead.

Comment: sorry for respondig a little too late, the problem was from Choice box that was designed to be used with a low number of items, combobox solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use ChoiceBox only if you have < 10 items, else use ComboBox